# JavaScript I need help validating and making an error message appear

Tags: javascript

```
function Pin(valid) {

    var Num;
    var Attempts = 0;

    while (Attempts < 3) {
        Attempts = (Attempts + 1);
        Num = prompt('Enter the pin number');

        if (Num != '12345') {
            alert('Wrong pin number, this is attemp ' + Attempts + ' of 3');
        } else {
            alert('Welcome!');
            valid = true;
            return valid;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I need help in showing me how to make an error message appear after 3 failed tries and end the program. I have tried many ways but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: You'll have to store the `Attempts` as a cookie or in local storage

Comment: In javascript there is really no ending the program.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `valid` argument?

Comment: If you really want the user to be blocked you need to do it at server side.

Answer (score 1):

If the loop finishes, it means the user exceeded the max number of attempts. So show an error message there.

```
function Pin(valid) {

    var Num;
    var Attempts = 0;

    while (Attempts < 3) {
        Attempts++;
        Num = prompt('Enter the pin number');

        if (Num != '12345') {
            alert('Wrong pin number, this is attemp ' + Attempts + ' of 3');
        } else {
            alert('Welcome!');
            return true;
        }
    }
    alert('Too many failed attempts, giving up');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: everytime the function is called Attempts be be set to 0

Comment: Looks like @Ani was similarly confused when he suggested using a cookie or LS above.